# При запуске бота с двух аккаунтов, бот отвечает только одному

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Cуть в том что при запуске бота, когда ему пишут одну команду два разных аккаунта, ответы засчитываются только тому аккаунту, который первый дал команду.
Вроде понимаю в чем дело,(бот не слушает сообщения после дачи команды)но поправить никак не могу!

```
async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

{

```
if (update.Message is not { } message)
    return;

if (message.Text is not { } messageText)
    return;

var chatId = message.Chat.Id;

Console.WriteLine($"Received a '{messageText}' message in chat {chatId}.");



var offset = 0;
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        var updates = await botClient.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);

                Console.WriteLine($"New message received from {message.Chat.FirstName}: {message.Text} in {chatId}");

                switch (message.Text)
                {
                    case "/start":
                        string text = "Здравствуйте, на ответ дается 6 секунд.Если ответ не будет дан за это время, все зависимости от его правильности, он будет считаться не правильным! Итоговые результаты вы сможете увидеть в конце опроса. Набор команд: /quiz Начать опрос";

                        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, text);
                        break;
                    case "/quiz":

                        offset = update.Id + 1;
                        var playerId = message.From.Id;
                        if (!States.TryGetValue(chatId, out var state))
                        {
                            state = new QuestionState();
                            States[chatId] = state;
                        }

                        if (state.CurrentItem == null)
                        {
                            state.CurrentItem = quiz.NextQuestion();
                            state.questionIndex = 0;
                        }
                        Stopwatch sw = new();

                        while (state.questionIndex < quiz.Questions.Count)
                        {
                            var question = state.CurrentItem;
                            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, question.Question);

                            var answer = "";
                            while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
                            {
                                updates = await botClient.GetUpdatesAsync(offset: offset, timeout: 100);
                                message = updates.FirstOrDefault()?.Message;

                                if (message != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Text))
                                {
                                    answer = message.Text.ToLower();
                                }
                            }
                            sw.Start();

                            offset = updates.LastOrDefault().Id + 1;




                            if (answer == question.Answer.ToLower() && sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 6000)
                            {
                                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                                    chatId: chatId,
                                    text: "Верно!",
                                    cancellationToken: cancellationToken); ;
                                if (PlayerScore.ContainsKey(playerId))
                                {
                                    PlayerScore[playerId]++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    PlayerScore[playerId] = 1;
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                                    chatId: chatId,
                                    text: "Не верно !",
                                    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                            }

                            state.CurrentItem = quiz.NextQuestion();
                            state.questionIndex++;
                            sw.Stop();

                            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                            sw.Restart();

                        }

                        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                            chatId: chatId,
                            text: "Тест окончен!",
                            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                        int score = PlayerScore[playerId];
                        int test = quiz.Questions.Count;
                        using (StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(pathToLog, true))
                        {
                            await swr.WriteLineAsync(($"{message.Chat.FirstName} набрал {score} очков в {DateTime.Now}"));
                        }


                        if (score == 0)
                        {
                            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                                chatId: chatId,
                                text: "Ни одного правильного ответа",
                                cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

                            PlayerScore[playerId] = 0;
                            state.questionIndex = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: chatId,
                                text: $"Вы набрали {score} из {test} очков ",
                                cancellationToken: cancellationToken);


                            PlayerScore[playerId] = 0;
                            state.questionIndex = 0;


                            break;

                        }

                    default:

                        break;

                }

                                
             if (update.CallbackQuery != null)
            {
                var callbackQuery = update.CallbackQuery;
                string buttonText = callbackQuery.Data;

                Console.WriteLine($"Callback query received from {callbackQuery.From.FirstName}: {buttonText}");

                await botClient.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(
                    callbackQueryId: callbackQuery.Id,
                    text: $"You pressed {buttonText}");
            }
            offset = update.Id + 1;

        await Task.Delay(1000);
        File.Delete("testKursk.txt");
        cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

   





}
catch
{

}
```

Comment: зачем код оборачивать в `while (true)` ?  Сделайте как в примере https://telegrambots.github.io/book/1/example-bot.html

Comment: @User12351259599491 уже убрал этот цикл, проблема все равно осталась

Answer (score 1):

Прошлый ответ был не правильный. Этот код обрабатывает каждое сообщение от каждого юзера отдельно.

```csharp
using Telegram.Bot.Polling;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Exceptions;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var botClient = new TelegramBotClient("");

            using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

            // StartReceiving does not block the caller thread. Receiving is done on the ThreadPool.
            ReceiverOptions receiverOptions = new()
            {
                AllowedUpdates = Array.Empty<UpdateType>() // receive all update types except ChatMember related updates
            };

            botClient.StartReceiving(
                updateHandler: HandleUpdateAsync,
                pollingErrorHandler: HandlePollingErrorAsync,
                receiverOptions: receiverOptions,
                cancellationToken: cts.Token
            );


          
             var me = await botClient.GetMeAsync(); 
           

            //Console.WriteLine($"Start listening for @{me.Username}");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Send cancellation request to stop bot
            cts.Cancel();


            async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            { 
                Task task = Task.Run(() => { 
                // ТУТ ВАША ЛОГИКА 
                if (update.Message is not { } message)
                    return;
                // Only process text messages
                if (message.Text is not { } messageText)
                    return;

                var chatId = message.Chat.Id;

                Console.WriteLine($"Received a '{messageText}' message in chat {chatId}.");
                
                int count = 0;
                if (message.Text == "/test")
                {
                        var sentMessageTest = botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                           chatId: chatId,
                           text: "Вы написали:\n" + messageText,
                           cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                        var sentMessageLogic =  botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                          chatId: chatId,
                          text: "Выполняем работу ",
                          cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                    ChatId ChatId = new ChatId(message.Chat.Id);
                    while (true) 
                    {

                            var sentMessageCount =  botClient.EditMessageTextAsync(ChatId, sentMessageLogic.Result.MessageId, sentMessageLogic.Result.Text+ " "+count);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        count++;
                        if (count == 60) 
                        {
                            var JobDone =  botClient.EditMessageTextAsync(ChatId, sentMessageLogic.Result.MessageId, "Работа выполнена");
                            return;
                            

                        }

                    }
                   

                }


                });


                // Echo received message text

            }

            Task HandlePollingErrorAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var ErrorMessage = exception switch
                {
                    ApiRequestException apiRequestException
                        => $"Telegram API Error:\n[{apiRequestException.ErrorCode}]\n{apiRequestException.Message}",
                    _ => exception.ToString()
                };

                Console.WriteLine(ErrorMessage);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }


    }
}
```